# Pandas Group by Multiple Columns and Levels of Values and Append Results to the Original Data Frame

Tags: python, pandas, group-by

I have a data frame and would like to group it by a few columns and different levels of values. Also, I want to append the group by results to the original data frame.

This is the original data frame:

```
  AAA BBB CCC 
  x1  y1  yes 
  x1  y1  yes  
  x1  y1  no   
  x1  y2  no
  x2  y2  yes
  x2  y2  no
```

This is what I want:

```
  AAA BBB CCC Yes No
  x1  y1  yes 2   1  
  x1  y1  yes 2   1
  x1  y1  no  2   1
  x1  y2  no  0   1
  x2  y2  yes 1   1
  x2  y2  no  1   1
```

The idea here is that I want to group by AAA and BBB and count yes/no in CCC for each group. Then, I want to add the count values into 2 new columns, Yes and No.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way is to:

- group by `AAA` and `BBB`
- get the `value_counts()` of `CCC` for each group
- unstack the innermost value-count index (which consists of `yes` and `no`) into the columns
- merge the counts with the original DataFrame

```
counts = (df.groupby(['AAA', 'BBB'])['CCC']
            .value_counts()
            .unstack()
            .fillna(0)
            .astype(int))

counts.columns = counts.columns.str.title()

pd.merge(df, counts, left_on=['AAA', 'BBB'], right_index=True)

  AAA BBB  CCC  No  Yes
0  x1  y1  yes   1    2
1  x1  y1  yes   1    2
2  x1  y1   no   1    2
3  x1  y2   no   1    0
4  x2  y2  yes   1    1
5  x2  y2   no   1    1
```

Comment: @MAMS, great to hear :)